# Is it correct and natural to say "guide someone on how to do something"?

Tags: prepositions

Would you tell me if it is correct and natural to say *guide someone on how to do something*? For example:

> I'll **guide** you **on** how to fix the laptop in a minute.

I've refered to online dictionaries, but none of them gives examples with *on*. If it is not natural, would you provide some natural sounding alternatives.

Comment: It's in use. I found examples with the help of Ngram (searched 'guide you on') but you are right that there's nothing on major online dictionaries (I looked it up on OALD, Cambridge, Longman and Macmillan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not sound natural.  I would use *through* instead of *to*.  A more natural sounding alternative would be:

> I will guide you through fixing the laptop in a minute.

"Guide on" would more typically refer to guide as a noun.  You could create a *guide on* something, for example:

> I will create a guide on fixing the laptop in a minute.

Guide is a noun in that usage. You are creating something the other person can refer to that will help them fix their laptop.

Comment: Are you aware of the ambiguity in your suggested answer?

Comment: @RonaldSole I was not.  Is that better or is it missing the ambiguity still?

Comment: That fact that your answer is ambiguous doesn't make it wrong.  Your answers could mean either: 1. In a minute, I will create a guide etc. or 2. I will create a guide that will enable you to fix a laptop within the space of a minute..